# Extending POI properties in SXA

Tags: sxa

I read about the Map, Map provider, POI, etc ... in SXA

I have a question:

Can I, or should I add additional data to POI ( like opening hours )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly simple.

Just extend POI template with your "Opening Hours" field:

[image]

You can find this template here:

`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Geospatial/POI`

Duplicate existing "Default" Rendering Variant under `/sitecore/content/{Your Tenant}/{Your Site}/Presentation/Rendering Variants/POI` and add a new Renderer for your new field (by duplicating Title for example):

[image]

Create POI under `/sitecore/content/{Your Tenant}/{Your Site}/Data/POIs/` and fill in "Opening Hours" field:

[image]

Add a Map component to your page. Choose your POI in "POI" field and set "POI Type to Rendering Variant Mapping" field to your newly created Rendering Variant like this:

[image]

Of course best would be to create your own template that inherits from POI template and add new field there. This would be cleaner solution. You shouldn't change original templates. In this case maybe you need to duplicate existing Map component and implement some logic to use your Enhanced POI template instead of OOTB one.